Making forecasts based on cyclical data
I am trying to develop a more robust methodology for a forecast model. This attempts to project the final number of recruits for this cycle based on comparing the current recruitment cycle to previous recruitment cycles. Simplifying it greatly, if we had double the recruits so far, we would project double the number of recruits at the end of the cycle.
I’ve been trying to read up on the subject, but I don’t even have the right terminology to know what to look for - what type of model would be best/what am I looking for?

You may want to look at seasonal ARIMA, or SARIMA, where you very roughly speaking model seasonal differences as ARIMA. That said, I find your argument interesting. I have also seen the opposite proposition: "If we had double the demand as last year so far, that means we will have lower demand going forward, because obviously people are just pulling demand forward in time." This sometimes goes by "forecast consumption".

That’s a really helpful suggestion, thank you! And yes, you’ve pointed out one of the issues we’re trying to work out - distinguishing the applications that have been brought forwards from the ones we can treat as additional. I’m not sure of any way to do that robustly without incorporating other variables, but I will look into SARIMA thank you!!
